# Using Protovis with Dynamically Loaded Data via JQuery

Tags: jquery, protovis

I am dynamically loading some social network data into a web page that I want to visualise using protovis.(Actually, the data is loaded in in a two pass process - first a list of user names is grabbed from Twitter, then a list of social connections is grabbed from the Google Social API.) The protovis code seems to run inside an event loop, which means the data loading code needs to be outside this loop.

How do I load the data into the page and parse it, before "switching on" the protovis event loop? At the moment, I think there's a race condition whereby protovis tries to visualise network data that hasn't been loaded and parsed yet?

```
<html><head><title></title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../protovis-3.2/protovis-r3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

//getNet is where we get a list of Twitter usernames
function getNet(){

  url="http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=jisc11&callback=?"
  $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    users=[]
    uniqusers={}
    for (var u in json['results']) {
      uniqusers[json['results'][u]['from_user']]=1
    }
    for (var uu in uniqusers)
      users.push(uu)
    getConnections(users)
  })
}

//getConnections is where we find the connections between the users identified by the list of Twitter usernames
function getConnections(users){
  //Google social API limits lookup to 50 URLs; need to page this...
  if (users.length>50)
    users=users.slice(0,49)
  str=''
  for (var uic=0; uic<users.length; uic++)
    str+='http://twitter.com/'+users[uic]+','
  url='http://socialgraph.apis.google.com/lookup?q='+str+'&edo=1&callback=?';

  $.getJSON(url,function(json){
    graph={}
    graph['nodes']=[]
    userLoc={}

    for (var uic=0; uic<users.length; uic++){
      graph['nodes'].push({nodeName:users[uic]})
      userLoc[users[uic]]=uic
    }

    graph['links']=[]
    for (u in json['nodes']) {
      name=u.replace('http://twitter.com/','')
      for (var i in json['nodes'][u]['nodes_referenced']){
        si=i.replace('http://twitter.com/','')
        if ( si in userLoc ){
          if (json['nodes'][u]['nodes_referenced'][i]['types'][0]=='contact') 
            graph['links'].push({source:userLoc[name], target:userLoc[si]})
        }
      }
    }

    followers={}
    followers={nodes:graph['nodes'],links:graph['links']}
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  users=['psychemedia','mweller','mhawksey','garethm','gconole','ambrouk']
  //getConnections(users)
  getNet()
})

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="center"><div id="fig">
    <script type="text/javascript+protovis">
      // This code is taken directly from the protovis example
      var w = document.body.clientWidth,
        h = document.body.clientHeight,
        colors = pv.Colors.category19();

      var vis = new pv.Panel()
        .width(w)
        .height(h)
        .fillStyle("white")
        .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.pan())
        .event("mousewheel", pv.Behavior.zoom());

      var force = vis.add(pv.Layout.Force)
        .nodes(followers.nodes)
        .links(followers.links);

      force.link.add(pv.Line);

      force.node.add(pv.Dot)
        .size(function(d) (d.linkDegree + 4) * Math.pow(this.scale, -1.5))
        .fillStyle(function(d) d.fix ? "brown" : colors(d.group))
        .strokeStyle(function() this.fillStyle().darker())
        .lineWidth(1)
        .title(function(d) d.nodeName)
        .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag())
        .event("drag", force)
        //comment out the next line to remove labels
        //.anchor("center").add(pv.Label).textAlign("center").text(function(n) n.nodeName)

      vis.render();

    </script>
  </div></div>

</body></html>
```

Comment: does my updated answer solve your problem now?

Comment: I've blogged a demo using James Crook's solution w/ JQuery making queries to Twitter and Google Social APIs, then graphing the result: blog.ouseful.info/2011/04/12/using-protovis-to-visualise-connections-between-people-tweeting-a-particular-term/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`vis.render()` is currently being called before you get the data.  There may be other issues too, but it needs to be after `getNet()`.

---

**EDIT 1:**

`vis.render()` is now after `getNet()`.  I've put the protovis force layout creation code inside a function so that I can control when it executes, and made the `vis` and `followers` variables visible to both the initialization code and the `createLayout` code.

Protovis, particularly the force layout, is very unforgiving about errors - e.g. wrong structure or count of elements for nodes/links datastructure, and does not tell you what is going on, so in developing it is best to first use static data that you know is of the right kind, and then later replace with dynamically created data.

One part of the problem you were having is that using `type="text/javascript+protovis"`
 invokes javascript rewriting by protovis.  The code below uses `type="text/javascript"` and has the extra `{}`s and `return`s that using `+protovis` saves.  This allows `getJSON()` and protovis to coexist in Chrome browser, without `getNet()` being called repeatedly.

```
<html><head><title></title> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="protovis-d3.2.js"></script>

<body>
<div id="center"><div id="fig">

<script type="text/javascript">
var vis;
var followers={};

function createLayout(){
    var w = document.body.clientWidth,
    h = document.body.clientHeight,
    colors = pv.Colors.category19();

    vis = new pv.Panel()
      .width(w)
      .height(h)
      .fillStyle("white")
      .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.pan())
      .event("mousewheel", pv.Behavior.zoom());

    var force = vis.add(pv.Layout.Force)
      .nodes(followers.nodes)
      .links(followers.links);

    force.link.add(pv.Line);
    force.node.add(pv.Dot)
      .size(function(d){ return (d.linkDegree + 4) * Math.pow(this.scale, -1.5);})
      .fillStyle(function(d){ return d.fix ? "brown" : colors(d.group);})
      .strokeStyle(function(){ return this.fillStyle().darker();})
      .lineWidth(1)
      .title(function(d){return d.nodeName;})
      .event("mousedown", pv.Behavior.drag())
      .event("drag", force);
      //comment out the next line to remove labels
      //.anchor("center").add(pv.Label).textAlign("center").text(function(n) n.nodeName)
  vis.render();
}

function getNet(){
  // OK to have a getJSON function here.

  followers={nodes:[{nodeName:'mweller', group:6},
    {nodeName:'mhawksey', group:6},
    {nodeName:'garethm', group:6},
    {nodeName:'gconole', group:6},
    {nodeName:'ambrouk', group:6}
  ],
  links:[
    {source:0, target:1, value:1},
    {source:1, target:2, value:1},
    {source:1, target:4, value:1},
    {source:2, target:3, value:1},
    {source:2, target:4, value:1},
    {source:3, target:4, value:1}]};
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  getNet();
  createLayout();
})
</script>

</head> 

</div></div>

</body></html>
```

**EDIT 2:**

In case you are interested in digging a bit deeper, the problem comes from this code in protovis:

```
pv.listen(window, "load", function() {
   pv.$ = {i:0, x:document.getElementsByTagName("script")};
   for (; pv.$.i < pv.$.x.length; pv.$.i++) {
     pv.$.s = pv.$.x[pv.$.i];
     if (pv.$.s.type == "text/javascript+protovis") {
       try {
         window.eval(pv.parse(pv.$.s.text));
       } catch (e) {
         pv.error(e);
       }
     }
   }
   delete pv.$;
 });
```

The technique I've used to use `"text/javascript"` and avoid using `"text/javascript+protovis"` both solves your problem AND makes it easier to debug code using protovis in Firefox.

Comment: Yes - and I can't see how to call vis.render() when I want from the type="text/javascript" code rather than the type="text/javascript+protovis" code?

Comment: Thanks for that additional edit; the problem I was having - and still get - is that if i put a $.getJSON call into the getNet() function, it seems to get called repeatedly (Chrome, OS/X 10.5.8)? My assumption was that there's an event loop running to keep the protovis animation going, and that somehow the getJSON call is getting invoked within that loop context?

Comment: Updated example to avoid javascript rewriting in Chrome browser.

Comment: Thanks James - just one minor tweak to your code - createLayout() is better in the getNet() function I think, so it isn't called until the graph is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

Great job James - only one thing to watch out for: If you keep the `createLayout()`; call within the jQuery `$(document).ready()` function you might find your panel appearing in the wrong place... if you want the panel to appear within the div your script is in, remove the jQuery refs and all should be fine.

**Edit:**
I wasn't aware of the canvas parameter in Protovis at the time I wrote this - simply adding canvas `divid` to the panel, plus a div with that id, takes care of positioning issues completely.